# How to post a file to Django/DRF using python requests

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I have the following code to post a json dataset/file to a Django/DRF API db.

I get the error message

```json
{"ohlc":["No file was submitted."]}
```

what am I doing wrong ?

```py
test_url = "http://localhost:8000/stocks/aapl/price/"

test_file = {
    "aapl": open("./ohlc_aapl.json", "rb")
}

payload = x.to_dict(orient='records')

r = requests.post(test_url, 
                  files=test_file,
                  json=payload)
```

the payload looks as the following

```json
[{'date': '2020-08-27 00:00:00',
  'open': 508.57,
  'high': 509.94,
  'low': 495.33,
  'close': 500.04,
  'adjusted_close': 124.2111,
  'volume': 155552408},
 {'date': '2020-08-28 00:00:00',
  'open': 504.05,
  'high': 505.77,
  'low': 498.31,
  'close': 499.23,
  'adjusted_close': 124.0099,
  'volume': 187629920},
   ...
```

Comment: the error is saying that no files were submitted, so the problem is with the `test_file` not the payload, what's in `test_file` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your serializer expects the file under the `ohlc` field and you're posting `aapl` instead.

Try this.

```
        fname = "ohlc_aapl.json"
        with open(f"./{fname}", "rb") as fb:
            response = requests.post(
                url=test_url,
                files={
                    'ohlc': (fname, fb)
                },
                json=payload,
            )
```